# migration laravel don't fill class name

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

hello my problem is when create a migration always don't fill class name, I Must write it manualy:
[image]

is there any hope?

Comment: Which version of laravel ?

Comment: can you add your command too ?

Comment: see this issue : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/42030, i think you have stubs that are not in sync with laravel, perhaps you used stub:publish command in the past ? In that case you will need to update them, or simply delete them if you don't need them

Comment: @Lk77 laravel 9 how to update stub:publish ?

Comment: You will have to change the stub by hand, look at stubs/migration.stub and set it to `return new class extends Migration` instead of `class {{ class }}`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name :

```
   php artisan migrate:fresh

Create :

php artisan make:migration create_flights_table
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

Comment: thank you for answering but I'm use create model with -m (create migration)

Answer (score 0):

if you migrated from laravel 8/9 to 10

You should check your stub folder
migration.create.stub file has changed